# ¿Cómo copiar datos de un json a otro json para cada elemento que está contenido en los geojson de el otro?

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

Tengo un archivo geojson con resultados para cada provincia y una que da otros resultados para cada circunscripción (una parte administrativa de la provincia).  Es decir, en el dibujo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría hacer una tercera que ponga los resultados de la primera para cada nivel de la segunda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Significa que todos los constituences de la misma provincia tendrán los mismos resultados que provienen de `research.json`. Ahora mismo estoy tratando de hacerlo en la clave name_2 pero sé que habrá momentos en los que fallará. Así que necesito una solución alternativa, he estado pensando en Geojson.

Aqui esta `constituences.json`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "totalFeatures": 1515,
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ],
              [
                -7.27286911,
                33.24623871
              ],
              [
                -7.26732922,
                33.25904083
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 1,
        "name_4": "Ahlaf",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.27286911,
          33.22112656,
          -6.93353081,
          33.38970184
        ],
        "swing_count": 1,
        "polling_station_count": 15,
        "turnout": 0.4780299144225693,
        "results": {
          "PI": 187,
          "PJD": 88,
          "PAM": 59,
          "USFP": 1530,
          "APFGD": 2,
          "PPS": 15,
          "RNI": 708,
          "MP": 56,
          "UC": 3,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 8,
          "PEDD": 0,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 0,
          "USAPMD": 10
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 5953,
          "nbre_votants": 2997,
          "nbre_nuls": 328,
          "nbre_exprimees": 2669
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.06666666666666667
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.2",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.00001287,
                33.63414383
              ],
              [
                -7.00081205,
                33.6269989
              ],
              [
                -6.99825382,
                33.60465622
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 2,
        "name_4": "Ain Tizgha",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.12737417,
          33.57954407,
          -6.99144888,
          33.78071213
        ],
        "swing_count": 11,
        "polling_station_count": 23,
        "turnout": 0.3912592182242994,
        "results": {
          "PI": 1837,
          "PJD": 366,
          "PAM": 143,
          "USFP": 22,
          "APFGD": 44,
          "PPS": 773,
          "RNI": 109,
          "MP": 111,
          "UC": 9,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 76,
          "PEDD": 27,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 2,
          "USAPMD": 514
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 8262,
          "nbre_votants": 4479,
          "nbre_nuls": 443,
          "nbre_exprimees": 4036
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.4782608695652174
      }
    }
  ],
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
    }
  },
  "bbox": [
    -13.2287693,
    27.62881088,
    -0.93655348,
    35.96390533
  ]
}
```

Y aqui esta `research.json`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81124878
              ],
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81097412
              ],
              [
                -7.18319511,
                33.81097412
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.1",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Ben Slimane",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 24,
            "intention_rate": 20.83
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 10,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 12,
            "intention_rate": 8.33
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 4,
            "intention_rate": 75
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 44.44
          },
          "RNI": {
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 100
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 55
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -6.3649292,
                33.22292328
              ],
              [
                -6.38369083,
                33.21116257
              ],
              [
                -6.39487886,
                33.19342422
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.2",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Khouribga",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 46,
            "No": 12,
            "Yes": 13,
            "total": 71,
            "intention_rate": 18.31
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 79,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 84,
            "intention_rate": 1.19
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 14,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 19,
            "intention_rate": 21.05
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 12,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 7,
            "total": 20,
            "intention_rate": 35
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 8,
            "intention_rate": 25
          },
          "RNI": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 5,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 214
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -3.77662611,
                34.86683655
              ],
              [
                -3.7705431,
                34.86468506
              ],
              [
                -3.75482011,
                34.86924362
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.57",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Taza",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 28,
            "Yes": 14,
            "total": 58,
            "intention_rate": 24.14
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 29,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 32,
            "intention_rate": 3.12
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 9,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 23,
            "total": 36,
            "intention_rate": 63.89
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 11,
            "intention_rate": 45.45
          },
          "RNI": {
            "total": 0,
            "intention_rate": 0
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 2,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 55.56
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 152
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

He hico [un script en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358031/c%C3%B3mo-copiar-datos-de-un-json-a-otro-json-para-cada-elemento-que-est%C3%A1n-contenido?noredirect=1#comment644856_358031), pero no está optimizado, estoy tratando de hacerlo mejor con javascript.

Comment: ¿La solución la necesitas en `Python` o en `Javascript`? Me parece que una de las dos etiquetas esta sobrando.

Comment: @Marcos Cualquiera de los dos me viene bien. :)

Comment: Los dos son GeoJSON y deseas combinarlos imagino de tal forma que las propiedades que se repitan no sean sobreescritas, si no que mas bien tener una forma de conservar ambas propiedades con ambos valores, pero esto no es posible directamente, sin embargo no creo que sea necesario... es decir, si ambos son GeoJSON y ambos tendrán casi el mismo contenido, porque no simplemente hacer un array que los contenga a ambos?, asi un objeto no afectara al otro y ambos tendrán sus propiedades y valores por aparte.

Comment: Si tu meta es simplemente unir ambos json sin afectar las propiedades que se repiten en ambos del primero y mantener las que no del segundo, temo que no se puede de manera sencilla, la recursividad en este caso se torna compleja debido a que hay que comprobar en ambos objetos y en cada subobjeto que esas propiedades no hacen parte de ambos objetos para poder añadir las propiedades del segundo, en caso contrario conservar las del primero.

Comment: O simplemente deseas fusionarlos sin tener en cuenta aquello descrito arriba??

Comment: @Riven Sí, me gustaría que cada propiedad de los elementos de la `constituencies.json` fuera reemplazada por las propiedades del elemento de `research.json` que las contiene pero manteniendo algunos de ellos (`name_2` y `name_4` que son el nombre de la provincia, que designa el elemento con el que se relaciona en la `research.json`, y el nombre de la circunscripción, que es el suyo propio). Por ejemplo, si `a1` (constiuency) está en `A` (a province), entonces obtiene todas las propiedades de A pero mantiene `name_2` y `name_4`.