# ¿Cómo copiar datos de un json a otro json para cada elemento que están contenidos en las claves del otro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Tengo un archivo geojson con resultados para cada provincia y una que da otros resultados para cada circunscripción (una parte administrativa de la provincia).  Es decir, en el dibujo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría hacer una tercera que ponga los resultados de la primera para cada nivel `constituency` de la segunda que tenga la misma *province* con la primera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Significa que todos los constituences de la misma provincia tendrán los mismos resultados que provienen de `research.json`. Ahora mismo estoy tratando de hacerlo en la clave name_2.

Aqui esta `constituences.json`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "totalFeatures": 1515,
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ],
              [
                -7.27286911,
                33.24623871
              ],
              [
                -7.26732922,
                33.25904083
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 1,
        "name_4": "Ahlaf",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.27286911,
          33.22112656,
          -6.93353081,
          33.38970184
        ],
        "swing_count": 1,
        "polling_station_count": 15,
        "turnout": 0.4780299144225693,
        "results": {
          "PI": 187,
          "PJD": 88,
          "PAM": 59,
          "USFP": 1530,
          "APFGD": 2,
          "PPS": 15,
          "RNI": 708,
          "MP": 56,
          "UC": 3,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 8,
          "PEDD": 0,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 0,
          "USAPMD": 10
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 5953,
          "nbre_votants": 2997,
          "nbre_nuls": 328,
          "nbre_exprimees": 2669
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.06666666666666667
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.2",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.00001287,
                33.63414383
              ],
              [
                -7.00081205,
                33.6269989
              ],
              [
                -6.99825382,
                33.60465622
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 2,
        "name_4": "Ain Tizgha",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.12737417,
          33.57954407,
          -6.99144888,
          33.78071213
        ],
        "swing_count": 11,
        "polling_station_count": 23,
        "turnout": 0.3912592182242994,
        "results": {
          "PI": 1837,
          "PJD": 366,
          "PAM": 143,
          "USFP": 22,
          "APFGD": 44,
          "PPS": 773,
          "RNI": 109,
          "MP": 111,
          "UC": 9,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 76,
          "PEDD": 27,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 2,
          "USAPMD": 514
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 8262,
          "nbre_votants": 4479,
          "nbre_nuls": 443,
          "nbre_exprimees": 4036
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.4782608695652174
      }
    }
  ],
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
    }
  },
  "bbox": [
    -13.2287693,
    27.62881088,
    -0.93655348,
    35.96390533
  ]
}
```

Y aqui esta `research.json`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81124878
              ],
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81097412
              ],
              [
                -7.18319511,
                33.81097412
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.1",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Ben Slimane",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 24,
            "intention_rate": 20.83
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 10,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 12,
            "intention_rate": 8.33
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 4,
            "intention_rate": 75
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 44.44
          },
          "RNI": {
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 100
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 55
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -6.3649292,
                33.22292328
              ],
              [
                -6.38369083,
                33.21116257
              ],
              [
                -6.39487886,
                33.19342422
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.2",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Khouribga",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 46,
            "No": 12,
            "Yes": 13,
            "total": 71,
            "intention_rate": 18.31
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 79,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 84,
            "intention_rate": 1.19
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 14,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 19,
            "intention_rate": 21.05
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 12,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 7,
            "total": 20,
            "intention_rate": 35
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 8,
            "intention_rate": 25
          },
          "RNI": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 5,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 214
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -3.77662611,
                34.86683655
              ],
              [
                -3.7705431,
                34.86468506
              ],
              [
                -3.75482011,
                34.86924362
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.57",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Taza",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 28,
            "Yes": 14,
            "total": 58,
            "intention_rate": 24.14
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 29,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 32,
            "intention_rate": 3.12
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 9,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 23,
            "total": 36,
            "intention_rate": 63.89
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 11,
            "intention_rate": 45.45
          },
          "RNI": {
            "total": 0,
            "intention_rate": 0
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 2,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 55.56
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 152
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

He empezado un script en Python, lo compartiré con vosotros tan pronto como salga al menos algo sin errores, pero estaré contento con javascript tambien. Intenté el siguiente código:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def find_segment(province_queried):
    with open('research.geojson', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        dct_research = json.load(f)
        for feature in dct_research['feature']:
            for key in feature.get("properties", {}).get("results", {}):
                province = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name")
                segments = feature.get("properties", {}).get("segments")
                if province == province_queried:
                    return segments

def main():
    with open('constituencies.json') as f:
        dct_constituencies = json.load(f)

    for feature in dct_constituencies['features']:
        for key in feature.get("properties", {}).get("results", {}):
            province = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name_1")
            constituency = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name_4", {})
            segments = find_segment(province)
            d.append({"Party Affiliation": key,
                      "Province": province,
                      "Constituency Name": constituency,
                      "segments": segments})

    column_names = ["Province", "Constituency Name", "Party Affiliation", "segments"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=column_names)

    df.to_csv("constituencies_with_segments.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pero es muy lento. ¿Cómo puedo optimizarlo?

Comment: ¿Popular la tabla `costituences.json` relacionando el `name_2` con `name` de `research.json` no sirve?

Comment: @VRoxa Sí, pero ¿cómo se hace para cada constitución de circunscripciones. json que tiene el mismo nombre?

Comment: La solución más elegante que se me ocurre, realmente es crear un objeto que agrupe ambos *json* e implementar un [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) que relacione `name_2` con `name`. Siendo sincero, nunca he implementado nada parecido, pero los `Proxy` en *JavaScript* sirven, entre otras cosas, para hacer este tipo de *metaprogramación*.

Comment: @VRoxa Hmm, no lo sabía. Gracias por la información, todavía estoy un poco débil con el javascript. Publicaré mi intento en Python. Pero sigue zumbando.

Comment: [Aquí](https://youtu.be/_5X2aB_mNp4?t=862) te dejo una conferencia muy instructiva sobre una implementación de lo que he comentado ahora. Creo que puedes replicar exactamente este escenario. (A partir del minuto 14.30, aprox.). Lamento no poder ayudarte en *Python*, es un tema pendiente que tengo por aprender, (:

Comment: @BetaM, Gracias por compartir el enlace, pero no hay respuestas y el lenguaje no es el mismo. Aquí tengo un intento en Python. Y, es un detalle, soy el autor del enlace que compartes conmigo :)

Comment: @BetaM No, no lo borre es el mismo problema, pero no los mismos enfoques. Este es más sobre la optimización del código. El otro es un intento de hacer lo mismo pero en javascript para un único propósito educativo.

Comment: Jaaaaaa ^^^ le veo. Grcais